# Magento2 import sales tax rates via admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, csv, tax-class, tax-rates

I have a Excel file saves as a .csv and no matter what I do it keeps saying invalid file format.

I exported the excel the tax rates that where on the site then edited the file in excel and saved as csv

Answer (score 1):

I m also facing the same issue, I was export and check csv columns and compare and update header column than import, it was worked for me.